# Unable to reset systemd watchdog timer

Tags: linux, watchdog

I am using an embedded linux environment. I have created a service which starts a qt application.

```
[Unit]
Description=AutoStart App

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStartPre=/home/root/Clean_Application.sh
ExecStart=/home/root/Startup_Script.sh
WatchdogSecs=10min
NotifyAccess=all
Restart=always
StartLimitInterval=5min
StartLimitBurst=4
StartLimitAction=reboot-force

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Then I try to reset the timer by running the following steps.

```
export NOTIFY_SOCKET=/run/systemd/notify

systemd-notify READY=1
```

I then get the `MAINPID` by using the `systemctl status` command,
set the `MAINPID` with `systemd-notify MAINPID=$PID`
and try to reset the timer by running

```
systemd-notify WATCHDOG=1
```

I have tried every combination of this setup but nothing resets the timer.  I  tried changing `type=notify`and running `systemd-notify "WATCHDOG=1"` but nothing seems to work.

How can I troubleshoot this script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was able to achieve the software watchdog.
By doing this.

```
#include <systemd/sd-daemon.h>

sd_notify(0,"READY=1"); //in my constructor

sd_notify(0,"WATCHDOG=1"); // in my timer every 10 seconds.
```